# Weird Duplicate Entry Error on Primary Key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a live project more than 5 years. And today i had a weird mistake. I wanted to update some of my products. And there exists a duplicate entry error.

[image]

I have no field as product_id in my products table. 12479 is id of my product. id is primary key and auto increment.

Firstly, i think it can be an laravel problem. I query mysql directly via phpmyadmin. It is same. But only for this product.

Here is my indexes.

[image]

Here is my table structure

[image]

I repaired my db from plesk also. Nothing change. Sometimes it works correctly.

Error from phpmyadmin

[image]

And the weirdest one is, this error occured when i update stock_quantity field. I can update other fields without problems.

I noticed a mysql bug while searching 
**MySQL Bug:** https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68360

What should i do ?

Comment: That looks like a Doctrine error! And the fields it tries to update don't seem to bear much relation to the table you're showing. Has a Doctrine class been accidentaly changed?

Comment: it is not related with doctrine. Because when querying from phpmyadmin same error.

Comment: It says product_id not id can you try this ? `select* from (table you got product_id)  where product_id = 12479`    you probably made product_id unique after you put data to the table so now you have duplicate entry there

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem. (Mysql Error Handling is not good. Descriptions must describe the situation better)

I had a trigger for stock_quantity. If a product sold out and get in stock again. I'm sending mail to customers. In that table(products_notify) product_id is unique. And the products which has ids on products_notify fails.

Thanks @Rodrane

Comment: `Mysql Error Handling is not good` - no, it's good. You got information about everything, the table, the column, the constraint, the value.. what more could you need? You can't blame the system for being "bad" if you don't know how to use debug information.

Comment: The Error : duplicate entry 12479 for key 'product_id' i have more than 30 relations with products product_id. I mean which table caused ? It is missing.

Comment: The one you tried to update/insert into, it's not like you can have more than one column with the same name in the table.